# Config ip-based on nginx

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-config

Is there any possibility to place a config line for nginx that would execute only for certain ip?
Something like if ip==...
Then do ...
I have achieved this goal via code but I need here server level setting.
Thanks

Comment: if ($remote_addr = 8.7.6.5) {
    rewrite ^ http://www.example.com;
}

Comment: Can you please place an entire config note as answer?

Answer (score 1):

As requested in the comments;

You could solve this by checking the [`$remote_addr`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) var;

```
server {
    server_name ....;
    if ($remote_addr = 8.7.6.5) {
        rewrite ^ ...
    }
}
```

If you wish to go even further, take a look at the [Geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html);

```
geo $special_user {
  default 0;
  8.7.6.5/32 1;
  3.4.3.4/32 1;
}

server {
  if ($special_user) {
    rewrite ^ .....;
  }
}
```